# Display multiple values for each y-axis series in high charts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Passing the values to y-axis series like below:

```
this.chartOptions = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: [
            [0,38.6],
            [0,49.8],
            [1,39.2],
            [1,41.1],
            [1,46.6],
            [2,44]
        ],
      color: '#004191',
      showInLegend: false,
      name: 'price',
      threshold: 40,
      negativeColor: '#F34336',
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 3,
        symbol: 'circle',
      },
    },
  ],
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Days',
    },
    categories: ["16-Jan", "15-Jan", "14-Jan"],
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'price',
    },
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    min: 10,
    max: 100,
    tickPixelInterval: 35,
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false,
    showTable: false,
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        menuItems: ['downloadPDF'],
      },
    },
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
};
```

But the issue is the multiple values are rendering in the view but the values are not displayed in the tooltip on mouse hover of particular value.

**Case:** When I hover on **49.8** it shows tooltip but won't show for **38.6**. Even though they belongs to 1st series of y-axis.

[image]

Soution required:

1. Should display every value in the tooltip of y-axis on mouse hover.
2. I need to display multiple values in the tooltip(i,e display,rtMode,initMode).

Attaching stackblitz [ref](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-mhzgzx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to achive by following steps:

- First, instead of the line series, use scatter type. Set `lineWidth: 2` just to simulate line series.
- Next, adjust the tooltip via `headerFormat` (to use identical as original line series) and more advanced `pointFormatter`:

  ```
  tooltip: {
       headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 0.8em">{point.key}</span><br/>',
       pointFormatter() {
         let pointFormat = '',
         hoveredPoint = this;

         this.series.points.forEach(point => {
           if (point.x === hoveredPoint.x) {
             pointFormat += `<span style=\"color:${point.color}\">●</span> ${point.series.name}: <b>${point.y}</b><br/>`
           }
         })
         return pointFormat
       }
     },
  ```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ts7bcjwo/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Now the PDF download functionality breaking. Getting some undefined error. Attaching stackblitz ref >> https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-ashh7o?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: First thing, you need to include export server module: `import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'; HC_exporting(Highcharts);` Secondly, the error is occurring because the reference lineChart is not able to find, so you need to include it in html; Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-ybgp1m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

### Have multiple series

By the example I've seen here:

[https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33780#:~:text=http%3A//jsfiddle.net/aykutyararbas/rry1sdhm/](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33780#:%7E:text=http%3A//jsfiddle.net/aykutyararbas/rry1sdhm/)

you could add a new whole series with the data points you'd like to see but just make the series invisible.

**OR**

### Show additional tooltip Data

just only show **additional tooltip Data** like here (**Surely useful for rtMode and initMode, etc.**):
[https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=48914#:~:text=https%3A//jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e7yuga5d/](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=48914#:%7E:text=https%3A//jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e7yuga5d/)

I think the main problem is, that within HighCharts you can show multiple y-values that are on the same x-value **BUT** not within the same series.

I'm sorry I couldn't find more. I hope this maybe helps.
Maybe it just doesn't work, and HighCharts wants you to only see one point:

[https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43897#:~:text=https%3A//jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ktwfopdn/](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43897#:%7E:text=https%3A//jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ktwfopdn/)